# DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents

Tags: android-espresso

Hi i am starting an activity from another on clicking button in espresso. Everything works fine at the first time and when the same method is called second time i am getting error like this please help me out solve this problem.

This is the method i am calling in two different places :

```
    private void sendMailTest() {

        onView(withId(R.id.bill_view_send_mail)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
//        Intents.init();
//        activityIntentsTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        intended(hasComponent(SearchBillSendMailActivity.class.getName()));
//        Intents.release();
        pauseTestFor(5000);
}
```

This is what i am getting :

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])

Recorded intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.AppointmentDiscountActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{amount=200.0, nameType=1}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2830}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2831}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2832}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2833}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:187)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:169)
at com.wenzins.lab.TestPrepareBill.sendMailTest(TestPrepareBill.java:341)
at com.wenzins.lab.TestPrepareBill.validateCardWithoutAddingItems(TestPrepareBill.java:502)
at com.wenzins.lab.TestPrepareBill.verifyInputs(TestPrepareBill.java:303)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1867)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])

Recorded intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.AppointmentDiscountActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{amount=200.0, nameType=1}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2830}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2831}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2832}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.bill.BillViewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]], extras:[Bundle[{billingInvoiceId=2833}]])
-Intent { cmp=com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe/com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity } handling packages:[[com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe]])
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:87)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:282)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:190)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you an accurate answer without seeing the Espresso test in question, but if your button click is firing off the Intent for com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.popup.SearchBillSendMailActivity, this behavior makes total sense.

You can resolve the issue in one of several ways:

Use the times(int times) VerificationMode as part of your Intents.intended() call or:

call Intents.release() after verifying your Intent was fired after the first button click.

Either way, post your test and your desired end state for a better answer.

Comment: yeah i  have tried both said ways but still got the same error.

Comment: The complete test isn't posted.  The method posted is not a complete test.  What test rule are you using?  Are there any @Before/@After?  What else is happening as part of this test? What is the onclick for the button doing?

Comment: This test case just calls this intent one after the other by clicking send Button